# Custom animation

Tags: android, animation, sliding

How to implement this type of animation with sliding effect and color transition in android. (IOS like sliding controller).
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is not even a question.

Comment: If you want then do it.

Answer (score 0):

try the my sample code

activity_main_activity2

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity2">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){

        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();


        fList.add(new Fragment1());
        fList.add(new Fragment2());

        return fList;

    }



    class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;

        }

        @Override

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }


        @Override

        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


}
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_left_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/select"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/me"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="First Page"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_One.java

```
public class Fragment_One extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


        return v;

    }

}
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_left_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/select"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/me"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Second Page"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_two.java

```
public class Fragment_two extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: color transition  is our paradigm not the transition. hope you can help us